How to handle separate Design Systems for B2C and B2B from one company
Our company offers apps (B2C) and a web dashboard software (B2B), which both target completely different user groups.
We're now at a point internally, where we're discussing if we should go with one single design system with different UIs in there or we completely separate them into two.
It seems logical to most of us that two separate files are better for everyone involved, but some also raised the point that as a company we should still try to follow a similar approach on the basic structure of everything (like buttons components and states, etc.).
Does anyone have experience with this and would have a good reason against two separate systems?

I can think of a few arguments against having two separate design systems:

Duplication of effort - You risk rebuilding things that already exist in one system or the other
Precedent - You're showing the organization that some products are allowed to not adopt the core design system. You'll hear a lot more "but my product is also special and deserving of its own design system"
Brand divergence - Instead of creating products that look like they belong in the same family, you're risking having one team go one way and the other team go a vastly different way. The point of design systems is to prevent this.
Resources - If resources become reduced, one or both systems might become hard to maintain, and one is likely to wither while the other receives priority

So in most cases it's better to have one core design system file, with components and  variants that support different cases. A good example is developer portals - lots of core elements and patterns shared between a company's marketing site and the dev portal, serving very different audiences, but they stay bound together through the same elements.

Really useful contribution, thank you. Fluent's design organization could be a useful discussion ground for us.

I usually work on enterprise applications where the clients (companies) already have a DSL for the B2C apps. In two different occasions specifically working for the banking industry we had the same issue that you're facing right now, "Our users were not the clients". So, based on this tenet we had some kind of freedom since at the beginning we tried to use the components from the DSL and not all the components were useful because our apps were dense in data and propose a new component to the library always was rejected because we didn't reach the right percentage to get an approval on the changes.
So, the approach that I saw was working was to create a branch from the main library and named it as Enterprise apps. We had more freedom to modify tables, cards and other composed components that we needed to modify for our apps and we still had updates on the atomic components like buttons, typography and text inputs that were inherited from the main library.
It was really painful at the beginning, however when you find your track you don't need to maintain your library because it still is connected to the main library.
Happy designs. ‍
